# Android widget Update based on current time

Tags: android, android-widget

I built a  clock widget and I want it to update every minute and I have set the UpdatePeriodMilis to 60,000 and for some reason it won't update every minute.

I have no Idea how much time passes before it updates but certainly not less then 5 minutes,which is the amount of time I could patiently look at the widget, waiting for an update.

How can I make it so that it will update every round minute?

Thaank you, I appreciate your help!